# How to add Dynamic pages on moodle?

Tags: moodle

Is there any way to add dynamic content in Moodle pages? I have used Pages Plugin to create pages but I am not getting a way to add dynamic
content in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic content"? like dynamic content in emails? I usually embed dynamic parts in the page, but if you know some JS you can write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this - a workaround which allows your greater flexibility on the content displayed and a limited amount of html using a plugin.

1. **The workaround** So, my way around this would be to create two or three different pages - and then use the 'restrict access' function to only allow certain people to see each page. This allows you the greatest flexibility over content on the page, but you'd only be able to control access on a group level e.g. only students with a certain grade, gender etc.

Find out more here: https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Restrict_access_settings

2. **HTML** The generico plugin allows you to insert text strings into html on a page. It's pretty easy to use, but there's a limit to what you can do with it.

https://moodle.org/plugins/filter_generico

Answer (score 0):

My way to to add Dynamic pages on moodle is to add php-script somewere on server to moodle_data directory and add `iframe` to page using html-editing mode, ex.:

```
<iframe> src="/my/myscript.php"</iframe>
```